# Filter table with multiple date columns by date range

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to create a table in powerbi where each column draws data independently but cannot find a way to do that.

Dataset example and desired result example in the image

[image: image: dataset and desired result example]

The result is filtered by date period (start date, end date). Trying to filter one column, unfortunately filters the other as well (which destroys the result...)
How can I implement this in PowerBI?

Comment: You need unpivot https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/unpivot-column  And please post sample data and desired results as text instead of an image.

Comment: This looks like a group and count rather than unpivot

Comment: It's 'unpivot' since calculated tables are static.

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a **calculated table** with SUMMARIZE, since calculated tables don't recalculate on filter changes. So you first have to bring all the dates into one column to be able to filter on them. This is done by **unpivoting** your dataset.

```
Unpivoted Dataset =
UNION (
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        'Dataset',
        "Client", 'Dataset'[Client],
        "Product", 'Dataset'[Product],
        "Type", "RequestDate",
        "Date", 'Dataset'[RequestDate]
    ),
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        'Dataset',
        "Client", 'Dataset'[Client],
        "Product", 'Dataset'[Product],
        "Type", "DemoDate",
        "Date", 'Dataset'[DemoDate]
    ),
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        'Dataset',
        "Client", 'Dataset'[Client],
        "Product", 'Dataset'[Product],
        "Type", "OrderDate",
        "Date", 'Dataset'[OrderDate]
    ),
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        'Dataset',
        "Client", 'Dataset'[Client],
        "Product", 'Dataset'[Product],
        "Type", "ShppedDate",
        "Date", 'Dataset'[ShppedDate]
    ),
    SELECTCOLUMNS (
        'Dataset',
        "Client", 'Dataset'[Client],
        "Product", 'Dataset'[Product],
        "Type", "DeliveryDate",
        "Date", 'Dataset'[DeliveryDate]
    )
)
```

Next you need a Date table for your slicer with

```
Date = CALENDARAUTO()
```

Then you create a relation between the Date columns.
Finally you have to define measures for each count:

```
RequestsNum = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNT('Unpivoted Dataset'[Date]),
    'Unpivoted Dataset'[Type] = "RequestDate"
)

DemosNum = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNT('Unpivoted Dataset'[Date]),
    'Unpivoted Dataset'[Type] = "DemoDate"
)

OrdersNum = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNT('Unpivoted Dataset'[Date]),
    'Unpivoted Dataset'[Type] = "OrderDate"
)

ShppedNum = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNT('Unpivoted Dataset'[Date]),
    'Unpivoted Dataset'[Type] = "ShppedDate"
)

DeliveryNum = 
CALCULATE(
    COUNT('Unpivoted Dataset'[Date]),
    'Unpivoted Dataset'[Type] = "DeliveryDate"
)
```

Putting everything together on a report page you get

[image]

or

[image]

Comment: Did the answer help to solve your problem?